# Which cartoon character is she referring to? And what does this conversation "How's my house?" "Fulfilled" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

When I read a comic book called "Thief of Thieves" by Robert Kirkman, I encountered this conversation between the thief (Redmond) and his ex-wife (Audrey). They meet at the restaurant.

> Redmond: May I? (He takes a seat)
>
> Audrey: Sorry, but no, I'm waiting for someone. My date.
>
> Redmond: That's odd, is he running behind?
>
> Audrey: I take it you're bugging my calls again?
>
> Audrey: At least tell me you didn't steal his car.
>
> Redmond: Or his phone?
>
> Audrey: You're **like a cartoon character**, you know that?
>
> Redmond: **How's my house?**
>
> Audrey: **Fulfilled.**

Does somebody know which cartoon character she is referring to? And what does she mean by "fulfilled"? Does she mean she is satisfied with her current life without ex-husband?

Your kind help is much appreciated.

Comment: For context, is Aubrey living in the house she got from Redmond in the divorce? If so his question is probably literal, though I'm not sure about her response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any cartoon character she could be talking about. I'm not sure trying to find out is on topic here on ELL. It might be on a different SE. As for the English language usage, I think she is simply using figurative language to describe him. She is saying that he is unbelievable,  audacious, and intrusive, like many cartoon characters. I think it's also a joke, since he is in fact a character in a comic book.

As for the house, I think your interpretation is likely what she meant.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer, Max! My understanding became clearer now.